# Javascript for toggling visibility of table cell

Tags: javascript, html-table, toggle, cell, visibility

I have a code which creates html reports.

It uses html tables to display the results, the tables are sortable, and they are zebra striped automatically, so there is already Javascript and its all embedded inline, so that the file can be simply shared with its users.

I don't have a great grasp of Javascript, and doing that already was hard enough. However, a problem now is that sometimes some of the cells have A LOT of data in them. It is by design however, and I am hoping to find an elegant solution to this.

What I would like is a Javascript function or suite of functions where I can press on any cell in my table and have it toggle visibility.

In other words - there is a table with many cells rows and columns. When the user presses one cell, its contents are invisible, so the rest of the table will re-size itself. Thus - a cell with many lines of content which re-sizes the rows height, will collapse in size.

In this method, many rows of data which have a cell which heightens it can be compared much easier since the large cell is invisible.

I have found solutions which implement buttons outside the table to hide entire rows or columns. Buttons with input fields you can define an ID and have it hide that ID. I do not think it smart to have a different unique ID to each cell, I want something simpler.

A global function that catches any onclick event on a cell which well make that cells contents toggle visibility.

I know I have repeated my desire multiple times, but hopefully this has made my desire more clear.

Edit:

This is the final code I went for in the end. Seems to work nicely:

```
function tableclick(e) 
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    while(target != this && (!target.tagName || target.tagName != "TD")) target = target.parentNode;
    if( target != this) 
    {
        toggleVis(target)
    }
}

function toggleVis(obj) 
{
    if ( obj.style.fontSize != "0px" ) 
    {
        obj.style.fontSize = "0px"
    }
    else 
    {
       obj.style.fontSize = "16px"
    }
}
```

and then simply add `onclick=tableclick(event)` to your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an `onclick` event to the table, and look at the event's target.

```
table.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    while(target != this && (!target.tagName || target.tagName != "TD")) target = target.parentNode;
    if( target != this) {
        // "target" is the cell that was clicked. Do something with it.
    }
}
```

Side-note: You don't need JavaScript to zebra-stripe the rows. Just use CSS:

```
tr {background-color:white}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:black;}
```

Comment: looks great, where do i put this into the table code. 
could what type is the target, an elementID ?

Comment: Wherever, just make sure that `table` is defined and points to the table. `target` is an HTMLTableDataCellElement` - in other words a reference to the table cell itself.

Comment: No. `getElementByID` will give you an element, `target` is already an element.

Comment: i think i am putting the `table.onclick` in the wrong place. i have it under the script section. just as it is. and ofcourse my table is a simple table, am i missing something?

Comment: Did you define `table`? You need to get the table into it, maybe with `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: now it is working on a sample table of mine, but not on my main table... no idea why. basically i have `<table XXXXX onclick=tableclick(event)>` i named your function `function tableclick(e)` and i pass target to the function i linked, only i removed the part where it tries to get element ID. and that works on one table but not another, what could be possible reasons?

Comment: Are you sure you added the event to the main table? Do you have another `onclick` event already on that table? What happens if you add some `alert` calls through the code to see what's happening? Do any errors show up in the console?

Comment: okay, this is great. i made it work now. was some stupid mistake - but its only half my problem. function i use to hide the cell makes it unretrievable, i want to only hide its contents. how can i do that? is it possible to do this?

Comment: You could try `target.temp = target.innerHTML; target.innerHTML = "";` to hide, and `target.innerHTML = target.temp;` to show.

Comment: not good. since its huge tables with many cells. cant i set the table to not resize borders to fit contents? that way it will "collapse" on the content of each cell unless it is pressed. and pressing will toggle this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to learn, jQuery is the way to go.  It's a great javascript framework that will make your life much easier as you get more familiar with javascript.  jQuery has functionality to do just what you are saying.  Check out the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) on `toggle()`.

You would do something like this:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    $('td').show();
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

This would 'toggle' the visibility of any TD that you click.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aGumq/) is a fiddle.

Comment: i dont want to include external libraries, because all the code needs to be embedded into the document.

Comment: jQuery is NOT the way to go to *learn*. It may be the way to go once you *have learned*, but you should never start with jQuery if you want to have any hope of future progress. What happens if jQuery suddenly vanishes, hmm?

Comment: I must confess that I learned (insofar as I know anything much about) JavaScript through first experimenting with, and using, jQuery. And *then* learning about the DOM API almost by accident while trying to understand how jQuery worked. Not that I'd recommend the approach, as such, but it's not without its merits.