# JavaScript onclick conditional table cell

Tags: javascript, html, cell

I recently had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887085/javascript-for-toggling-visibility-of-table-cell/12887121#12887121) which I have since solved.

However, I now have a different problem. I want the code to only toggle the visibility of cells in the 2nd and 3rd columns.

I have no idea how to approach this, my knowledge of JavaScript is minimal.

Also, it would be nice but not a requirement, to have all the cells in 2nd and 3rd rows automatically toggled invisible.

**Edit:**

I have copied only over the soltution to my previous problem for ease.

```
function tableclick(e) 
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    while(target != this && (!target.tagName || target.tagName != "TD")) target = target.parentNode;
    if( target != this) 
    {
        toggleVis(target)
    }
}

function toggleVis(obj) 
{
    if ( obj.style.fontSize != "0px" ) 
    {
        obj.style.fontSize = "0px"
    }
    else 
    {
       obj.style.fontSize = "16px"
    }
}
```

Comment: no - the code is embedded into the files, these are report documents which are shared on our internal network. and possibly outside. cant rely on external libraries

Comment: Nothing stopping you hosting your own copy of the jQuery library

Comment: please no jquery, cant rely on network. it needs to be standalone.

Comment: Fair enough - but if you can't even "rely" on being able to host a single extra .js file on your network, then I would be slightly worried about the network in the first place

Comment: @freefaller listen - im not going to start discussing company policy or our network. suffice to say, these reports need to have all their script embedded. its the simplest implementation so that they can be shared dynamically without having to worry about external libraries, network connections, or anything else. all you get is in one nice file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tableclick(e) 
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    while(target != this && (!target.tagName || target.tagName != "TD")) target = target.parentNode;
    if( target != this && (target.cellIndex == 1 || target.cellIndex == 2)) 
    {
        toggleVis(target)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by doing something i never thought would actually work, but there you have it...

```
function tableclick(e) 
{
    var ColNum=1;
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1) {
        if(event.srcElement.tagName=="TD") {
            ColNum+=event.srcElement.cellIndex;
            }
        }
    else {    
        if (e.target == "[object HTMLTableCellElement]") {
             ColNum+=e.target.cellIndex;
             }
        }
    if (ColNum == 2 || ColNum == 3)
    {    
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    while(target != this && (!target.tagName || target.tagName != "TD")) target = target.parentNode;
    if( target != this) 
    {
        toggleVis(target)
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using browser sniffing (always a bad idea), if you already have working code, that gets the "target" browser independently? Your whole if-block basically does that same as `e = e || window.event;     var target = e.target || e.srcElement;`. See my answer...